# Single Type With Several Data Constructors vs. Several Types

Tags: haskell

Consider the following type which describes the structure of some 2-dimensional shapes:

```
data DrawingElem
    = Rect     Pos Size
    | Circle   Pos Radius
    | Ellipse  Pos Radius Radius
    | Line     Pos Pos
    | Polygon  [Pos]
    | Polyline [Pos]

    | Group    [DrawingElem]
    | Drawing  [DrawingElem]
```

which make use of these definitions:

```
data Vec    = Vec Double Double

type Pos    = Vec
type Size   = Vec
type Radius = Double
```

The last two data constructors of `DrawingElem` are somehow special, because they make tree-like arrangements of the other types possible.

```
mydrawing = Drawing [Rect (Vec 0 0) (Vec 10 10),
                     Group (Vec 30 40) [Circle (Vec 0 0) 90,
                                        Line (Vec 0 0) (Vec 50 50)]]
```

Such a data structure should finally being transformed into a renderable SVG-String:

```
toSvg :: DrawingElem -> String
toSvg (Drawing xs)               = "<svg>" ++ concatMap toSvg xs ++ "</svg>"
toSvg (Group xs)                 = "<g>" ++ concatMap toSvg xs ++ "</g>"
toSvg (Rect (Vec x y) (Vec w h)) = "<rect x='" ++ x ... "</rect>"
```

For this purpose, it looks to me it was necessary to wrap the different shapes inside the `DrawingElem` type. They must have the same type in order to be nested and finally rendered.

In some other occasions, I'd like them being different types however: Say for a function which sets the size of a rectangle (and this only makes sense for rectangles, the others don't have the notion of a size):

```
setSize :: Size -> Rect -> Rect
```

This of course does not work with the above definitions and must be:

```
setSize :: Size -> DrawingElem -> DrawingElem
setSize (Rect p s) = ..
setSize x          = x
```

So I'd have to implement a wildcard that makes the function complete. However writing `setSize someSize someCircle` without getting a type error looks problematic to me.

So finally I'm struggling with wrapping the drawing Elements inside a type VS. letting them being different types. Both properties are needed in different situations as described above.
Does someone have an advice for this? Is is an either-or, or is there maybe a way to model it which takes advantage of both ways?

Comment: I adjusted some of the syntax in your data type definition. Please check whether I changed anything that I wasn't supposed to.

Comment: Your initial edits were needed. However, it seems that you reverted them in another edit.

Comment: it definitely should be DrawingElement, hence should we rollback to revision 2?

Comment: I reverted them because I wasn't 100% sure that you intended `DrawingElem` and `Shape` to be the same thing (which would imply a group would be able to contain other groups, and a drawing other drawings). Given that that is the case, I will re-revert them.

Comment: the post looks like it was intended right now. However, it might be open to discuss if the introduction of another type Shape would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use another indirection layer, and have a precise type for each element:

```
data DrawingElem
    = DERect     Rect
    | DECircle   Circle
    ...

data Rect   = Rect Pos Size
data Circle = Circle Pos Radius

toSvg :: DrawingElem -> String
...

setSize :: Size -> Rect -> Rect
...
```

As a minor downside here we need to pattern match *both* layers, e.g.

```
toSvg (DERect (Rect pos size)) = ...
```

A more advanced alternative could be using a GADT. This might be overkill for your task, though.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}

data ElemType = Rect | Circle | ...

data DrawingElem (t :: ElemType) where
   DERect   :: Pos -> Size   -> DrawingElem Rect
   DECircle :: Pos -> Radius -> DrawingElem Circle
   ...

-- this works on all element types t
toSvg :: DrawingElem t -> String
...

-- this works only on a rectangle element
setSize :: Size -> DrawingElem Rect -> DrawingElem Rect
setSize size (DERect pos _) = DERect pos size
```

I am unconvinced about whether you actually need this. If in doubt, stick with the simpler alternative.

Comment: for the first approach there could be even a default constructor function like this: `rect f = toSvg . f $ (Rect (Vec 1 1) (Pos 0 0))`, which could then be used like this: `rect (fill Red . size 4 4 . pos 7 5)` . Or would you know another way to conveniently create shapes in such a system? The second approach, I'll keep in the pocket for further projects.

Comment: Just realizing that the `rect` constructor must be a bit more complex, e.g. setting a default color. However it should show the point.

Comment: @AntonHarald Yes, you can do that if you want. Sometimes record updates are used for a similar goal e.g. `defaultRect { pos = ... , size = .. }` where all unset fields are given by the default rectangle value.

Answer (score 2):

> However writing `setSize someSize someCircle` without getting a type error looks problematic to me.

That would be problematic indeed. To avoid that, I will suggest a third option: perhaps you don't actually need a rectangle-specific `setSize` function at all. An alternative approach would be keeping a single `DrawingElem` type, setting an initial size on rectangle construction (and the initial radius on circle construction, etc.) and using functions that can be implemented for all kinds of elements to adjust the size after construction, such as:

```
scale :: Double -> DrawingElem -> DrawingElem

scaleX :: Double -> DrawingElem -> DrawingElem

scaleY :: Double -> DrawingElem -> DrawingElem
```

That is very similar to how *gloss* handles shapes (cf. [the relevant type definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-rendering-1.9.3.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Rendering.html) and some [picture manipulation functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.10.2.3/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#g:1)). Another example worth mentioning is [*diagrams*](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html), which uses a very sophisticated model for pictures, with a plethora of types and classes involved, and yet handles operations such as scaling in a similar manner.

Comment: the example I gave was maybe not the best. For the scaling I think your approach is reasonable. However, there will be other properties which will differ much more in the shapes. For instance some of the shapes can be filled with a color, others not.

Comment: @AntonHarald Alternatives in that case might include using an indirection layer, as in chi's answer, and introducing a few different types to cover the insurmountable differences plus a common, "lower-level" intermediate representation supporting a minimal set of operations that you can convert the "higher-level" elements to when necessary (e.g. for grouping them).